# How a create a helper function which calls other functions passed as parameter

Tags: c#, testing, delegates, parallel.foreach

I have a function which i use for stress testing and i want to stress test multiple functions. The function that i am stress testing here is  `GetParameters(reportUri, SessionContext);`

How can i add a helper function in which i can pass a parameter such as an action body or a delegate (this is good but i have multiple functions with different paramters). and it executes all the steps by just replacing `this.RemoteReportingServiceFactory.CreateReportParameterProvider().GetParameters(reportUri, SessionContext);` dynamically. The entire function body is going to be same except for above mentioned line

```
public void GetParameters()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Log.Message(TraceEventType.Information, "Start of {0} sequential iteration with 5 parallel stress runs".InvariantFormat(i));
        Parallel.For(0, 2, parameterIteration =>
        {
            Log.Message(TraceEventType.Information, "Stress run count : {0}".InvariantFormat(parameterIteration + 1));
            string reportUrl = TeamFoundationTestConfig.TeamFoundationReportPath("TaskGroupStatus");
            ReportUri reportUri = ReportUri.Create(reportUrl);
            Log.Message(TraceEventType.Information, "ReportUri = {0}".InvariantFormat(reportUri.UriString));
            IList<Parameter> parameters = this.RemoteReportingServiceFactory.CreateReportParameterProvider().GetParameters(reportUri, SessionContext);
        });
    }
}
```

Let me know if am not clear enough. I can edit my questions as per requests

Answer (score 0):

How about changeing the method to something like

```
public void GetParameters(Func<ReportUri, SessionContext, IList<Parameter>> returnStuff)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Log.Message(TraceEventType.Information, "Start of {0} sequential iteration with 5 parallel stress runs".InvariantFormat(i));
            Parallel.For(0, 2, parameterIteration =>
            {
                Log.Message(TraceEventType.Information, "Stress run count : {0}".InvariantFormat(parameterIteration + 1));
                string reportUrl = TeamFoundationTestConfig.TeamFoundationReportPath("TaskGroupStatus");
                ReportUri reportUri = ReportUri.Create(reportUrl);
                Log.Message(TraceEventType.Information, "ReportUri = {0}".InvariantFormat(reportUri.UriString));
                IList<Parameter> parameters = returnStuff(reportUri, SessionContext);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Will parallel.For be working on the same list IList<Parameter>? Basically i want each method body inside Parallel.For to be executed on its own as .Net will be spawning its own thread. At the end i want to assert whether the list of parameters matches expected number

Comment: The last parameter of the `Func` decleration is the return result, so each instance should be local to the `Parallel.For` decleration.